# How can I get the url in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

When I click on the button, I try to check if I'm on the right page.

Here is my code:

```
describe('espace_parent is functional', () => {
  it('test login parent', () => {

    cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')
    cy.contains('parent').click()
    cy.contains('Espace Parent')



    cy.get(":input[placeholder='Adresse e-mail']").type('guigui@guigui.fr')
    cy.get(":input[placeholder='Mot de passe']").type('guigui')
    cy.contains('Se connecter').click() 


    cy.log('Current URL is ')
    cy.contains("Accueil")

  })
})
```

On this code, I am on localhost3000, I click on the parent who has to redirect me to localhost3000/connexion/parent and I want to login but I don't know if it's functioning or not.

I already tried to do different things to print the URL, but none work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use the `cy.url()`.

1. To print the URL you can use:

```js
cy.url().then((url) => {
  cy.log('Current URL is: ' + url)
})
```

2. If you want to validate the URL you can use:

```js
cy.url().should('include', '/connexion/parent')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the url with command [`cy.url()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/url) or [`cy.location()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/location).

You would use `cy.url()` like this:

```js
// with should()
cy.url().should('eq', 'http://localhost:3000/connexion/parent');
cy.url().should('include', '/connexion/parent');
// with then()
cy.url().then(url => cy.log('Current URL is', url);
```